# Load a local cached JavaScript file into a Webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have a JavaScript file in the cache folder and I need to load that into the html WebView in Android via Java. How I can do that?

I need to show JavaScript changes apply into the HTML page.

```java
  File cacheDir = getCacheDir();
        File javaScriptPath = new File(cacheDir, "ckEditor.js");

  String html = "<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
                "<html lang=\"en\">\n" +
                "<head>\n" +
                "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n" +
                "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + javaScriptPath.getAbsolutePath() + "\">" + "</script>" +
                "</head>\n" +
                "<body>\n" +
                "    <h1>Classic editor</h1>\n" +
                "    <form action=\"[URL]\" method=\"post\">\n" +
                "        <textarea name=\"content\" id=\"editor\">\n" +
                "            &lt;p&gt;This is some sample content.&lt;/p&gt;\n" +
                "        </textarea>\n" +
                "        <p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"></p>\n" +
                "    </form>\n" +
                "</body>\n" +
                " <script>\n" +
                "        ClassicEditor\n" +
                "            .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )\n" +
                "            .catch( error => {\n" +
                "                console.error( error );\n" +
                "            } );\n" +
                "    </script>" +
                "</html>";

        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(cacheDir.getAbsolutePath(), html, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8", null);
```